# Should I make a personal website so that I can write that on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search

There is always a field in a typical resume which is website. I don't have a personal website and don't like to make up stuff.

Although I've once built a website 10 years ago, I really do not like making websites. You need so many things to build a website, e.g: theme, content, design, hosting.

A website could possibly introduce a person better, but I think it could be too much. What do you think?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A website is a sample of your work.

What are you trying to highlight?  It sounds like you aren't doing web development... so highlighting that you can build a website doesn't really focus attention on your skills.

If you build a website, you need to have a solid, impressive system.  The worst thing I've seen was a website with shoddy HTML and misspelled words... it suggested that perhaps the candidate didn't care about the work, or didn't know right from wrong.  Anything you put out there is a means of judging you - show yourself in the best light.

Answer (score 4):

If the position you are applying for involved web development, then a personal website would be beneficial.

If the position requires a portfolio of graphic arts, animation, music...Then a website is a very good way to display some samples of your work.

Keep in mind that some customers will not allow you to show more than screen captures of the websites you created for them. Some won't even allow that.

But a website for the sake of having a website, doesn't help you in the job hunt.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a personal web site if you're passionate about something you want to document in a web site. A "home page" on the Internet is no longer impressive or worth showing to people who are considering you for employment. Don't create a website because "everyone else is doing it" or because you want to fill a field on a resume. It will be obvious and likely misunderstood by those who are looking at you for employment.

Say you do create a personal website because there's something you want to put out there (projects, writing, photos, etc), should you even include it on your resume? If it's something you're proud of and helps sell you to potential employers then you should include it. I only provide URLs for websites that are relevant to the position.